# Merging rows macro vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a list of customers where the customers are repeated across multiple rows. I'd like to merge cells that are similar in Column A, but not touch anything else.  If I could even format bold borders between customers, that'd be great.

Basically,
1 |  abc   |  abc
1 |  abc   |  def
1 |  def    |  xyz
2 |  abc   |
2 |  abc   |  def
3 |              |  xyz
4 |  abc   |  qrs
4 |  abc   |  def
5 |  mni   |  xyz

To

1 |  abc   |  abc
   |  abc   |  def
    |  def    |  xyz
2 |  abc   |
     |  abc   |  def
3 |              |  xyz
4 |  abc   |  qrs
    |  abc   |  def
5 |  mni  |  xyz

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to merge cells.  In fact, I recommend against it, that causes more problems than it solves.  What you could do is hide column "A", then insert an empty column "B" put this formula in "B2", then auto-fill:

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",A2)
```

Also, this solution avoids macros, which can be difficult and problematic if you are new to them.

For that "customer separator" formatting that you're looking for, use conditional formatting.  Here's a picture:

[image]

I got that tip from this web site:  [Conditional Formatting](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/highlight-excel-cells-based-on-the-value-of-anothe.html)